# GridView with dynamic item number per row in Universal Application

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to display a `GridView` which alternates a row with only one expanded item and a row that displays many items, let's say three.

In both of the cases, the items should fill the page width. This means that the row containing multiple items should divide the space in three equal areas.

My attempt was to use `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as item panel.

```
<GridView x:Name="rowGrid" IsSwipeEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AppCollection}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource HomeDataTemplateSelector}" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,12,0">
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Then I set `ColumnSpan` property inside the data template selector:

```
public class HomeDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate WideItemTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var lv = GetListView(container);
        if (lv != null)
        {
            var i = lv.Items.IndexOf(item);
            if (i % 4 == 0)
            {
                VariableSizedWrapGrid.SetColumnSpan(container as UIElement, 3);
                return WideItemTemplate;
            } else {
                VariableSizedWrapGrid.SetColumnSpan(container as UIElement, 1);
                return DefaultTemplate;
            }

        }
        return DefaultTemplate;
    }

    public static GridView GetListView(DependencyObject element)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var parentListView = parent as GridView;
        return parentListView ?? GetListView(parent);
    }
}
```

Here are the two templates for completeness:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultItemDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Height="170" Background="Transparent">
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="WideItemDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Height="170" Background="Transparent">
       ...
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is what I'm getting. It's like the first wide item propagates its width to the others elements.

[image]

I followed [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walaa/2014/02/22/gridview-multiple-item-templates/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set Orientation as "Horizontal" for VariableSizedWrapGrid. And you would have to set width for StackPanel which is in DataTemplate. Then it will work.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultItemDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Height="170"  Background="Transparent">
            <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="WideItemDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Height="170" Width="250" Background="Transparent">
            <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:HomeDataTemplateSelector x:Name="HomeDataTemplateSelector" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultItemDataTemplate}" WideItemTemplate="{StaticResource WideItemDataTemplate}"></local:HomeDataTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView x:Name="rowGrid" IsSwipeEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AppCollection}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource HomeDataTemplateSelector}" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,12,0">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kejg3.png)